# How to fix an excel cell with file directory attached?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I received a file from someone else and found that there are cells contain the following formulas:

`=@'C:\Program Files (x86)\HoadleyOptions\HoadleyOptions.xla'!HoadleyOptions1(C44,D12,D13,D14,D15,D16,D17,D18,D19,D22,C25:D36,D38)`}

I have the HoadleyOptions1 function available on my excel. Just want to know how can I get rid off
`@'C:\Program Files (x86)\HoadleyOptions\` for multiple cells at once. There are a lot of those cells.

Thank you!

Comment: Quickest way is to use the Text to Columns feature, delimited on \ then delete the columns with data you don't want. Then `concat` it back together.

Comment: A search and replace may remove the extraneous text in your formula

Comment: Find > **In formulas** > ,,, > Replace ?